# How to cover the US map with minimum number of 30 mile radius circles?

Tags: r, geolocation, geometry, gis, geospatial

I have a big data set of coordinates and would like to place them into a groups falling under 30 mile radius circles. And I need these circles to cover entire US land area. Overlapping circles are allowed. Is there a way to do this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If your circles are going to overlap (which they would have to), what do you want to happen when a point you're trying to categorize fits into two circles?

Comment: And where are the centers of those radius circles? A good starting point might be the `raster::buffer()` function to create spatial buffers of a given distance from a given central point

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Counted under both the circles.  The main goal is to able to cover the entire map with the 30 mile radius circles.

Comment: @davidnortes I would imagine the centers would be identified only after the circles are laid out. Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hoolymama/gis-util) a while back that will help you work with locations on earth.

You can see a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoolymama/56wzdtax/) I made that makes random points on a circle centered at some location. The code below is pasted from the jsfiddle because SO wants code when you include a fiddle link, but you are better off to go experiment with the fiddle. The function `pointAtDistance()` implements the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

For the packing, I'd attempt a [hexagon formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2014_November_8) - make a grid and eliminate those that don't intersect land. As the earth is a sphere, you should probably find the number of degrees longitude closest to the equator that represents your offset so that 30 mile circles still overlap. Then using that angle, the circles further north will overlap more than needed, but at least there won't be gaps, and the structure is easy to reason about.

```
function pointAtDistance(inputCoords, distance) {
    const result = {}
    const coords = toRadians(inputCoords)
    const sinLat =  Math.sin(coords.latitude)
    const cosLat =  Math.cos(coords.latitude)

    const bearing = Math.random() * TWO_PI
    const theta = distance/EARTH_RADIUS
    const sinBearing = Math.sin(bearing)
    const cosBearing =  Math.cos(bearing)
    const sinTheta = Math.sin(theta)
    const cosTheta =    Math.cos(theta)

    result.latitude = Math.asin(sinLat*cosTheta+cosLat*sinTheta*cosBearing);
    result.longitude = coords.longitude + 
    Math.atan2( sinBearing*sinTheta*cosLat, cosTheta-sinLat*Math.sin(result.latitude )
        );
    result.longitude = ((result.longitude+THREE_PI)%TWO_PI)-Math.PI

    return toDegrees(result)
}
```